# conda-build error: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, conda-build

Hej all,

I am trying to build a conda package for a little program I wrote. When I run `conda-build`, I get the error  `Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.`

I have researched this for some hours now (found the similar questions here, none of which solved my issue) and played with the meta.yaml file (below), but I didn't manage to get it to work. Does anyone have an idea what could be going on here?

meta.yaml:

```
{% set name = "genview" %}
{% set version = "1.0" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  git_url: https://github.com/EbmeyerSt/GEnView.git

build: 
  number: 0
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

requirements:
  host:
    - pip
    - python=3.6
  run:
    - python=3.6
    - pip
    - pandas
    - biopython >=1.68
    - numpy
    - time
    - sqlite
    - argparse
    - prodigal
    - diamond
    - blast
    - cd-hit
    - fasttree

test:
  commands:
          - genview_create_db.py --help

about:
  home: https://github.com/EbmeyerSt/GEnView.git
  license: GPLv3.0
  license_family: GPL3
  summary: Visualization tool for genomic sequences surrounding a gene
```

directory structure:

```
../genview:
  -script.py
  -Readme.txt
   /conda_receipe:
     -meta.yaml
```

To build the package, I run `conda-build /conda_receipe` from the genview directory. Does anyone have an idea what is going on here? Any clues would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the packaging scheme, you need a `setup.py` or a `pyproject.toml` in your project. They are configuration files to generate a package.

If you want to use a `setup.py` file, it is better to use `setuptools`:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(...)  # add your setuptools options
```

(See the reference for `setuptools` usage [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#basic-use)).

However, if you want to use a `pyproject.toml` instead, you can refer to the `build` project. You will have to write the `pyprojet.toml` file (which is an INI-like file).

See an example of using these files on this [repository](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject). It uses both files, so take a look on it to get an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am confused though - should not the receipe (meta.yaml) I posted in my question be used for installation instead of setup.py? This is at least how I interpret https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/recipes/build-without-recipe.html? The conda docs on the other hand (https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html) use a setup.py but do not explain what it should contain...

Comment: On the user guide you linked, they are using a `setup.py` implicitely (on the `bld.bat` or `build.sh` files). That `setup.py` provides the setuptools options to build the package metadata (author, classifiers, description, etc.). That file is standardised, you you should provide, at least, `import setuptools; setup()` on that file.

Comment: You were right, added a setup.py and the error was resolved!